# UIWebView Fails Loading Online PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I have a PDF stored online.  I try to access it with `UIWebView`.  The `UIActivityViewController` will start spinning, and then stop after about 5 seconds, never loading anything in the view.  The file is 12.4MB being tested on a very fast internet connection.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.316apps.com/QMCC/current.pdf"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)tick {
    if(!webview.loading)
        [activity stopAnimating];
    else
        [activity startAnimating];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on a (slow) internet connection and it did load in about 62 seconds.

Things you could try:

- Increase the timeout of your request (to 2 minutes, maybe your simulator or phone connection is actually as slow as mine).
- Just to clean things up a bit, don't use a timer to show/hide the activity indicator, use the `UIWebView` delegate methods, such as `webViewDidFinishLoad:`.

Here's my example code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.316apps.com/QMCC/current.pdf")!))
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        // Show your activity indicator.
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        // Hide your activity indicator.
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
        print("FAIL: ", error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try that out, thanks.  How does that look in Obj-C?  Rest of my code for entire app is in Obj-C

Comment: It's basically the same thing. In Objective-C, to make a class conform to a protocol you use `@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSObject>`, but in swift it's `class MyClass: NSObject, NSObject`.
Now, simply start typing the methods like `- (void)webViewDidSta...` and Xcode will autocomplete them for you.

Comment: Ok, I tried increasing timeout and still have issues with it not loading.   I am using my iPad pro right now, and I went to that website in Safari and it took 12 seconds to load the PDF. I open up the app which goes to the exact same URL, and I wait for over 2 1/2 minutes and it never loads it

Comment: You could try running this again on your iPad Pro, enabling the Develop tab in Desktop safari, and selecting your iPad Pro from the list. There you can select the web view and inspect it. You can then check the Console tab for JavaScript errors.